Using drift package in dart without flutter
I am developing a backend application in standalone dart without flutter. I am using drift package in my backend project for using sqlite in dart without flutter. But, it's someway using flutter libraries.
when I run my dart code, it gives errors. Can you please tell me how to use drift in dart without flutter.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
